# CakePHP 3 Get model and method name for Auth finder

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Anybody know how to get model and method name used in Auth `finder` option?

I know when I set custom `finder` can get the name from `$this->Auth->config();`, but how to this for default finder?

Comment: The default finder is named `all`, and it could also be retrieved via the authentication objects configuration. However, why do you need that information in the first place? The question smells a little [**xy-ish**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/227568).

Comment: @ndm: I wrote plugin that extend Auth component based on `finder`. I would like add plugin with minimum configuration..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone will use it:

```
$authenticate = $this->Auth->getAuthenticate('Form');

echo $authenticate->getConfig('finder');
```